# update objects before access using DetailView (Django)

Tags: python, django, updates, detailview

I am using DetailView in Django. I have a model including certain time field(`taxi_time`), and I would like compare the time and now. If `taxi_time < datetime.now()`, I want to change a field(`taxi_is_closed`) in the model from `False` to `True`.

So before users access the post, I need to (automatically) check the time and modify `taxi_is_closed`. How can I do it?

My `View.py` :

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'), name='dispatch')
class RecruitView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Recruit
    template_name = 'taxi/recruit.html'

    def has_permission(self):
        return self.request.user.profile.email_confirmed

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        error_message = '아직 인증이 완료되지 않았습니다. 이메일 인증을 완료해주세요! :)'
        if self.raise_exception:
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return render(self.request, 'taxi/info.html', {'error_message': error_message})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecruitView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #pdb.set_trace()
        img_var = self.get_object().taxi_popnow*10 + self.get_object().taxi_poptot
        img_name = str(img_var)
        context['img_name'] = img_name
        context['ApplyForm'] = ApplyForm()
        return context
```

MY `model.py` :

```
class Recruit(models.Model):
    taxi_time = models.TimeField('출발 시각')
    taxi_is_closed = models.BooleanField('마감', default=False)

   def chk_closed(self):

         now = datetime.datetime.now()
         taxi_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(self.taxi_date, self.taxi_time)
         is_full = self.taxi_poptot <= self.taxi_popnow
         is_past = taxi_datetime <= now
         if (is_full or is_past):
             self.taxi_is_closed = True
         else:
             self.taxi_is_closed = False
         self.save()
```

I picked only related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method to call `chk_closed` on `RecruitView`.

```
class RecruitView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    ....
    def get_object(queryset=None):
        obj = super(RecruitView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        obj.chk_closed()
        return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside your `get_context_data` function:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecruitView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #pdb.set_trace()
        img_var = self.get_object().taxi_popnow*10 + self.get_object().taxi_poptot
        img_name = str(img_var)
        if self.object.taxi_time < datetime.now():
            self.object.taxi_is_closed = True
            self.object.save()
        context['img_name'] = img_name
        context['ApplyForm'] = ApplyForm()
        return context
```